# Why does <Su,v>=<Tu,v> for all u and v imply that S=T? Any better method of proofing this?

Tags: linear-algebra

While going through Axler’s linear algebra algebra done right section of inner products, he often shows that two operators are equivalent if it satisfies the condition in the title or more specifically: if $T,S \in L(V)$ and $<Tu,v>=<Su,v>$ for all $u,v \in V$ Then $T=S$.

I know one way of proofing this is through using Riesz representation theorem: Let $u \in V$, Since $<v,Tu>$ is a linear functional for any $v \in V$, then it is uniquely represented by $<v,x>$ Where $x$ is a unique vector in $V$. If $x=Su$, then $Tu=Su$ and since u was chosen arbitrarily $Tu=Su$ for all $u \in V$ and thus $T=S$

The above feels long winded and rather indirect so i was wondering if there was any clearer and faster way to proof that the title is true.

Edit: Solved and understood, thanks a lot for the fast replies

Comment: Write $A = S - T$ and rearrange your condition to $\langle Au, v\rangle = 0$ for all $u$ and $v$; does that help? (If not, choose $v$ carefully in terms of $u$.)

Comment: I learned Riesz in functional calculus later in my studies. Its not necessary here.

Answer (score 4):

$
\langle Tu, v \rangle = \langle Su,v\rangle, \forall u,v \in V 
\Rightarrow
\langle (T-S)u, v \rangle = 0, \forall u,v
$

take $v = (T-S)u$, then $\|(T-S)u\| = 0, \forall u\in V \Rightarrow T-S = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$$<Tu,v>=<Su,v>\iff \langle\, (T-S)u,v\,\rangle =0$$

and since the above is true for all $\;u\in V\;$ and the only vector orthogonal to all vectors is the zero vector, we are done.

Comment: `\langle,\rangle` are your friends: $\langle x,y\rangle$